# IRC traffic while using tor

Tags: exit-relays, traffic-analysis

I sniffed the traffic using wireshark while using IRC via TOR, the traffic is encrypted of course cuz its done i in the application layer (i think, correct 4 me if i am wrong). now the traffic is still encrypted until it reaches the exit node. i know the server or anyone sniffing there on the exit node will not be able to know where did it come from.  Will it be encrypted at the exit node if i didnt use SSL ? i know its a dumb question but i need to make sure. thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the exit node, the traffic is like any other. If the service IRC, https, etc. is using encryption, then it is encrypted.

If the service isn't using encryption, i.e. http, telnet, ftp, etc. then there isn't any.

There's no way around it. Even if you were using a VPN, the connection between the VPN server and the website, irc, whatever would still be unencrypted.